# What do I have to change in Zend GData Spreadsheet so it will request version 3 of Google Spreadsheets API?

Tags: api, zend-framework, google-maps-api-3, spreadsheet, gdata

"Important: Versions 1 and 2 of the Google Spreadsheets API have been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012 and will be shut down on October 20, 2012. Migration to v3 should be simple, as it includes all the features of v1 and v2, thus you only need to stop specifying v1 or v2 with your requests. We recommend that you update your apps to send requests to v3 as soon as possible."
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

I use Zend Gdata 1.11.12 to access the Google Speadsheets Api.

**What do I have to change in Zend GData Spreadsheets so it will request version 3 of Google Spreadsheets API?**

Kind regards,

Jan Nordgreen

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to change anything in your code, the PHP client library already uses the latest version of the Spreadsheets API. If that is not the case, you can always append the query parameter `v=3` to your requests to send requests to version 3 of the API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Could you please give me one example of where I would add the parameter?